# Can no longer load posts from certain categories

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm building a website like [www.reddit.com](http://www.reddit.com). I have Posts which can belong to eight categories. When a user clicks on a certain category, posts belonging to that category will show up. I was able to create the functionality to allow a user to do this and everything was working fine. I then made a search bar using the ransack gem and I got the search functionality working just fine. But now I can no longer click on categories to have the appropriate posts show up. I'm not sure how I messed this up and I have spent a considerable amount of time trying to figure it out. If anyone can point out the problem it would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Posts Controller:

```
  def index
    @search_posts = Post.search(params[:q])
    @search_results = @search_posts.result.paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 10)

    if params[:category_id]
      @category = Category.find params[:category_id]
      @posts = @category.posts.paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 10)
    else
      @posts = Post.paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 10)
    end

  end
```

Posts#Index View:

```
<%= search_form_for @search_posts do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_field :title_cont %>
  <%= f.submit "Search" %>
<% end %>

<% if @search_results.any? %>

  <% @search_results.each do |post| %>

    <div id="each_post">
      <p id="post_title"><%= link_to post.title, strip_url(post.url) %></p>
      <p>Submitted <%= time_ago_in_words(post.created_at) %> ago by <%= link_to post.user.name, user_path(post.user) %></p>
    </div>

  <% end %>

  <%= will_paginate @search_results %>

<% else %>

  <% @posts.each do |post| %>

      <div id="each_post">
        <p id="post_title"><%= link_to post.title, strip_url(post.url) %></p>
        <p>Submitted <%= time_ago_in_words(post.created_at) %> ago by <%= link_to post.user.name, user_path(post.user) %></p>
      </div>

  <% end %>

  <%= will_paginate @posts %>

<% end %>
```

I'm sure this is not the correct way to pass the category id's but I got it working like this:

```
<%= link_to 'Gadgets', category_posts_path(1) %>
<%= link_to 'Sports', category_posts_path(2) %>
<%= link_to 'Gaming', category_posts_path(3) %>
<%= link_to 'Pics', category_posts_path(4) %>
<%= link_to 'World News', category_posts_path(5) %>
<%= link_to 'Videos', category_posts_path(6) %>
<%= link_to 'Aww', category_posts_path(7) %>
<%= link_to 'Music', category_posts_path(8) %>
```

Posts is nested under categories:

```
  resources :categories do
    resources :posts
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

Try following link:

```
<%= link_to 'Gadgets', category_posts_path(:category_id => 1) %>
```

Comment: No luck. I may be wrong but I think the ID is able to get passed correctly. When I click on 'Gadgets', the link changes to http://localhost:3000/categories/1/posts.

Comment: Still it is not working? You sure you have posts associated with Gadgets category? Are you getting any error?

Comment: It's still not working. I get no errors. The URL changes with the category ID when I click one of the categories but nothing happens.